# Parsing date (00/09/2000) in IE

Tags: javascript, date

I am trying to parse date with formate like '00/09/2000' in IE.

IE or Edge:

[image]

We can see that the output is a date of Dec 09 1998. However, in browser other than IE, this will throw error saying invalid date.

Chrome:

[image]

My question is, how can we disable the behavior on IE?

Comment: Just a note, date formats other than YYY-MM-DD are browser dependent anyway..  For working with date's / time's, what I would suggest is using a library like moment.js.

Comment: You can't disable this behavior.

Comment: you probably want to place 00 with 12 whenever the date data comes in.

Comment: Can you share/provide more information about where you get the date `00/09/2000`?

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave you pretty much have all the info. I am using format like MM/DD/YYYY and someone inputs 00/09/2000

Comment: @JunbangHuang I don't know if is a good approach, but, since you said is in `MM/DD/YYYY` format, I should split the result and build a new Date instance, adding +1 to Month.

Comment: How to disable it? Every time a programmer writes code that uses the built-in parser, dock their pay 10%.

Comment: @RobG not quiet sure how is this one is duplicated

Comment: The duplicate explains that parsing of any format other than that defined in ECMA-262 is implementation dependent, the only fix for that is to not use the built-in parser.